# Como executar esse Curl em PHP?

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando executar esse Curl em PHP e não sei como converter ele. Segue o modelo:

curl -u "apikey:{apikey}" -X POST "https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v2/assistants/{idassistente}/sessions?version=2019-02-07"

Minha principal dúvida é nesse ponto aqui: -u "apikey:{apikey}" não sei fazer isso no Curl com PHP.

No terminal funciona. Quero passar essa lógica para o curl_exec do PHP.

Agradeço!

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida? `-u` ou `--user` especifica usuário e senha para autenticação no servidor.

Comment: A documentação do php é bem detalhada. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php
Dá uma olhada nessa documentação, mas como nosso amigo disse, você pode utilizar o curl_exec..

Comment: Estava olhando esse conteúdo semana passada, também bati cabeça! kkkk

Comment: Sim... eu quero passar essa lógica para o curl_exec() .... via terminal funciona... mas não sei passar para o curl_exec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar as funções [`curl_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) e [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) que são nativas do `PHP`, veja;

```
$ch = curl_init();
;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v2/assistants/{idassistente}/sessions?version=2019-02-07");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "apikey:apikey");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, []);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, []);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Note que não substitui nenhum valor genério como `{apikey}` ou `{idassistente}`, você pode fazer isso concatenando `strings`.

Comment: é isso que preciso... Só que acredito que a linha:
$header = ["apikey:"."{apikey}"];
ainda não está correto. tem certeza que o -u "apiey:..." vai no header assim?

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira tem razão, me confundi, agora existe a linha com `USERPWD`